# Arduino & ARM - Replacement for avr-libc?

Tags: programming, c++, arduino-due, c

There is very cool [avr-libc library](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html) that provides direct access for all functions of AVR microcontrollers. I'm writing a project for **Arduino Due** and I want to use timers and ISRs directly. Is there a library like `avr-libc` for ARM Cortex M3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the official library here: http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmel-arm-toolchain.aspx

**UPDATE:**

I have finally understood understand how **exactly** Arduino accesses specific ARM features. It includes `sam.h` file which in turn contains [Cortex Microcontroller Software Interface Standard](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/cmsis.html). With this cool interface anyone can use so many cool features:

- Timers
- Advanced interrupts
- Power saving mode
- SIMD instructions
- And many other

Answer (score 2):

I think `newlib` is the one you want.
[howto](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/using-newlib-in-arm-bare-metal-programs/)

Comment: Thanks, looks good. But it's more like a replacement for Arduino. May be there is something that could be imported to Arduino project like avr libc?